# Fluentd: Change host field (Splunk HEC output)

Tags: kubernetes, logging, splunk, fluentd, banzaicloud-logging-operator

I deployed the BanzaiCloud Logging Operator to send logs to Splunk using fluentd. Splunk interprets the source (host) as *fluentd-0* but I want to have the *$namespace.$pod* as the host field. I tried to override the field with record_modifier which ends up in having a second host field.

```
...
spec:
  filters:
  - record_transformer:
      records:
      - host: ${namespace_name}.${pod_name}
...
```

I also tried the replace function of record_modifier - without success.

```
spec:
  filters:
  - record_modifier:
      replaces:
      - key: host
        expression: /^fluentd-0$/
        replace: ${namespace_name}.${pod_name}
```

I think the host field is not part of the "log payload" and therefore can't be manipulated using [Record Modifier](https://banzaicloud.com/docs/one-eye/logging-operator/configuration/plugins/filters/record_modifier/) or [Record Transformer](https://banzaicloud.com/docs/one-eye/logging-operator/configuration/plugins/filters/record_transformer/.)

Can anyone tell me what I need to configure so the host field is replaced to namespace.pod?

Comment: I noticed that the host field is not part of the JSON log payload. No clue where Splunk has that information from.

Comment: what do your inputs.conf and output.conf files look like? Or, if sending via HEC, how has that been configured?

Comment: possibly related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50179871/4418

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution: The host field is generated by the Output and not by the Flow. So changing it like that:

```
apiVersion: logging.banzaicloud.io/v1beta1
kind: Output
spec:
  splunkHec:
...
    host_key: kubernetes.container_name
...
```

ended up in having the expected name as host instead of *fluentd-0*. Also *host* can be used instead of *host_key*, if it should be hard-coded.